# Can a meteor application be load balanced?

Tags: meteor

Is it possible to run multiple instances of a meteor application using Mongodb behind a load-balancer?

It seems that if multiple instances of an application are run on different servers then they would not know about changes to the Mongo DB made by other instances - and so not notify the clients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meteor is able to tell when the database is changed by another instance of meteor albeit with a slight delay (i've noticed up to 5 seconds max).

Load balancing shouldn't be challenging it is certainly possible.

You could use many meteor instances and a load balancer in the traditional sense quite easily.

Comment: Can it just tell changes by another meteor instance or changes to the MongoDB in general?

Answer (score 2):

This is completely possible with Meteor Cluster.

- Setting up Meteor Cluster - http://goo.gl/2aHJ2
- Setting up the load balancing - http://goo.gl/uvtVH